# 'Permission denied' when trying to delete file as root on macOS

Tags: macos, file-permissions, rm

I"m trying to delete:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel   507 Sep 22 04:10 com.mcafee.reporter.plist
```

on macOS 10.13.1:

```
 bash-3.2# rm -f /Library/LaunchAgents/com.mcafee.reporter.plist
 rm: /Library/LaunchAgents/com.mcafee.reporter.plist: Permission denied
```

I am root:

```
bash-3.2# whoami
root
```

It's a text file:

```
bash-3.2# file /Library/LaunchAgents/com.mcafee.reporter.plist
/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mcafee.reporter.plist: exported SGML document text, ASCII text
```

What's going on?

Comment: The file is probably open; looking at its name, I would guess it is one of the McAfee modules that has it. If you have it on OSX, `sudo lsof /Library/LaunchAgents/com.mcafee.reporter.plist` will show you all the programs that have a handle open to the file.

Comment: Could be ACLs or flags. What does `ls -@leO` show? Also, `ls -@leOd` on the directory it’s in?

Comment: Was this left over after you ran the uninstaller, or are you trying to manually pull it from a running instance? & why are you running as root? that makes no sense on a Mac.

Comment: `sudo lsof` does not print anything and just returns.

Comment: Using another file (also `Permission denied`): `ls -@leO UninstallCleanUp 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  - 3572 Sep 23 14:54 UninstallCleanUp`

Comment: macOS became extremely slow and started to act strange: Couldn't kill Mail, mails not sent and just disappeared, Xcode no longer building an app and just stalling, ...  I suspected McAfee and therefore wanted to get rid of it. I've now the uninstaller, run a disk sanity command, re-installed McAfee, and now all is back normal again.